# Get 2 DataFrames into 1

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-2.7, csv, classification

Hi everyone so I have a DataFrame about Pokemon data

```
data = pd.read_csv('pokemon.csv')
```

And I'm only interested in 2 columns 'type1' 'type2' (type2 can be null) as the same way the original videogame does. What I need is to get a DataFrame that looks like this:

[image: looking_for_dataframe]

data.type1 looks like this:

[image]

data.type2:

[image]

So basically I need to take a single DataFrames using those 2 columns.

I've code this stuff trying to get 2 DataFrame that I can turn into the final one I am asked to reach:

```
tabla = {}
def contar(tipo):
  buscando=tipo
  if tipo == np.NaN:
    pass
  else:
    if tipo in tabla:
      tabla[tipo] += 1
    else:
      tabla[tipo] = 1
tabla2 = {}
def contar2(tipo):
  buscando=tipo
  if tipo == np.NaN:
    pass
  else:
    if tipo in tabla2:
      tabla2[tipo] += 1
    else:
      tabla2[tipo] = 1

def reset_tabla():
  tabla = {}
  tabla2 = {}

data['type1'].apply(contar)
df_type1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tabla, orient='index')
reset_tabla()
data['type2'].apply(contar2)
df_type2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tabla2, orient='index')
df_types = pd.concat([df_type1, df_type2])
df_type1
```

So with above code I get the data I want but no the way I need it.
I expected:

[image: DF with 2 columns]

Instead, this was the output:

[image: 1 single column]

img continues and data appears 2 times due to 2 types columns

I think what I am doing wrong is the concat because type1 and 2 look like this separately:

[image: typ1]

and

[image: type2]

Finally, if you know how to combine these 2 DataFrames or you think you can solve this problem better let me know.

Thanks you all :).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue, so if it's useful for somebody the solution is here:

```
tabla = {}
def contar(tipo):
  buscando=tipo
  if tipo in tabla:
    tabla[tipo] += 1
  else:
    tabla[tipo] = 1

tabla2 = {}
def contar2(tipo):
  buscando=tipo
  if tipo == np.NaN:
    pass
  else:
    if tipo in tabla2:
      tabla2[tipo] += 1
    else:
      tabla2[tipo] = 1

def reset_tabla():
  tabla = {}
  tabla2 = {}

reset_tabla()
data['type1'].apply(contar)
data['type2'].apply(contar2)

for x in tabla2.keys():
  if type(x)==float:
    delete = x
del tabla2[delete]
types = {"type1": tabla,
         "type2": tabla2}

df_types = pd.DataFrame(types)
df_types
```

So I get

[image: Output]